# Finding circulation through a surface problem

Tags: calculus

The question was

$ \vec{F} = -z\hat{i} + y\hat{j} + z\hat{k} $

$C =$ the circle with radius $2, y=2$ centered around the $y$-axis and oriented counterclockwise when viewed from the positive $y$-axis.

I parameterized the curve so that:
$x= 2\cos(t), y=2, z=2\sin(t),$ and thus $d\vec{r} = (-2\sin(t),0,2\cos(t)). $

When I calculated $\int_c \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$  I got $8\pi,$ but the correct answer is $-8\pi.$

Can someone explain why I got the opposite sign of the correct answer? Is it due to the orientation?

Comment: + I do get the correct answer when I use Stokes' theorem to calculate this; but I'm unsure as to why I got the wrong answer using parameterization. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your parametrization is going the wrong way around the circle; that is, 
$$x=2\cos(t), y=2, z=2\sin(t)$$
doesn't square with "oriented counterclockwise when viewed from the positive $y$-axis." How did I discover this? By plugging in a few values. $t=0$ produces $\langle 2,2,0\rangle.$ But $t=\pi/2$ produces $\langle 0,2,2\rangle,$ which is going clockwise.

Try changing the $z$ component to $-2\sin(t),$ and re-calculate.